Autosar PDUR Handle ID generation Issue
I am currently working on Autosar Project, where I am facing the issue of PDU - Destination and Source Handle ID generated when ECU extract is imported.
Both the parameters are automatically getting configured by the Vector tool with 0 for all the PDU's.
enter image description here
Is it tool issue or extract issue. How this issue can be resolved?
